# What's the most efficient way of retrieving a batch of keys from an IndexedRDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, indexedrdd

I have an IndexedRDD typed:

```
IndexedRDD<String,HashMap<String,Double>>
```

with about 4 million key-value pairs. I was wondering what's the most efficient way of retrieving a batch of keys from an IndexedRDD? For example, given 10000 keys, I would like to retrieve 10000 key-value pairs efficiently, using the index for fast retrieval.

I tried using IndexedRDD.MultiGet(keys) but found that it gets the pairs one after the other and takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way to look up many keys is to create an RDD of the keys you want to look up, then inner join it with the IndexedRDD. This will do the lookup in parallel on each partition.

```scala
val keys = sc.parallelize(List("a", "b")).map(k => (k, 0))
val result = indexedrdd.innerJoin(keys) { (id, v, _) => v }
result.collect // => Array(("a", ...), ("b", ...))
```